# Python requests-html, trying to load all info in Jscript

Tags: javascript, python, screen-scraping, python-requests-html

Instead of visit this site that gives free proxies, I want to scrape the info and then filter it.  I'm trying to use requests-html to do this but so far following tutorial and reading the library it's not happening, when I run it it just outputs [].  Here is the code I have so far, I am trying to grab the part of the page that had the IP

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession



# create an HTML Session object
session = HTMLSession()


# Use the object above to connect to needed webpage
resp = session.get("https://advanced.name/freeproxy")

# Run JavaScript code on webpage
resp.html.render()

port = resp.html.find("data-ip")
print(port)
```

Comment: first see `print(resp.html.html)` - it uses some JavaScript to detect bots and it seems it works because it blocks your code. You may need something more for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add sleep time in render():

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = "https://advanced.name/freeproxy"

r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=2)

ips = r.html.find('tr > td:nth-child(2)')
ports = r.html.find('tr > td:nth-child(3)')

for ip, port in zip(ips, ports):
    print(ip.text + ":" +port.text)
```

Output:

```sh
186.96.117.28:9991
181.209.106.196:3128
181.209.86.210:999
115.77.191.25:9090
177.52.221.166:999
49.232.118.212:3128
45.235.110.66:53281
177.155.215.89:8080
191.242.230.135:8080
45.167.95.184:8085
170.83.76.73:999
142.44.148.56:8080
103.139.194.69:8080
102.134.123.167:8080
45.167.23.30:999
45.224.150.155:999
103.138.41.132:8080
170.239.180.58:999
103.160.56.16:8080
210.18.133.71:8080
185.179.30.130:8080
190.61.90.141:999
187.188.200.2:999
42.194.212.250:8081
88.157.181.42:8080
31.40.135.67:31113
218.60.8.99:3129
104.238.195.10:80
45.189.252.40:999
190.52.129.39:8080
103.151.226.133:8080
178.205.254.106:8080
186.233.186.60:8080
201.222.44.58:999
175.103.35.2:3888
177.21.237.100:8080
113.20.31.24:8080
190.108.93.82:999
158.140.162.70:80
36.75.246.41:80
190.120.252.245:999
167.172.180.46:42580
188.133.137.9:8081
191.234.166.244:80
47.101.59.76:8888
178.32.129.31:3128
202.142.189.21:8080
185.190.38.14:8080
203.75.190.21:80
222.74.202.229:80
223.82.106.253:3128
3.221.105.1:80
3.219.153.200:80
62.33.207.196:80
178.63.17.151:3128
111.90.179.74:8080
14.97.2.108:80
120.197.179.166:8080
68.15.147.8:48678
183.215.206.39:55443
221.6.201.74:9999
18.224.59.63:3128
61.153.251.150:22222
184.180.90.226:8080
162.243.161.166:80
103.148.195.37:4153
18.236.151.253:80
81.19.0.134:3128
78.47.104.35:3128
71.172.1.52:8080
65.184.156.234:52981
199.192.126.211:8080
125.99.106.250:3128
69.163.162.222:37926
173.236.176.67:17838
184.155.36.194:8080
216.75.113.182:39602
107.150.37.82:3128
159.65.171.69:80
45.43.19.140:33533
104.215.127.197:80
124.41.211.211:57258
103.216.82.20:6667
74.143.245.221:80
124.71.162.246:808
103.79.96.173:4153
47.57.188.208:80
69.163.166.126:37926
41.33.66.241:1080
131.0.87.225:52017
50.242.100.89:32100
103.78.27.49:4145
220.163.129.150:808
193.164.94.244:4153
203.215.181.219:36342
202.168.147.189:34493
106.52.10.171:9999
51.222.21.95:32768
122.155.165.191:3128
218.16.62.152:3128
```

Answer (score 0):

This page uses `JavaScript` to detect bots/scripts and it seems it works because it blocks your code. You may need something more for this.

If you check repo [requests-html](https://github.com/psf/requests-html) then you see it wasn't updated more than 1 year.

I can get it with Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
             
url = "https://advanced.name/freeproxy"

#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

all_ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-ip]')
all_ports = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-port]')
for ip, port in zip(all_ips, all_ports):
    print(ip.text, port.text)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Read next pages

- using `for`-loop and `url` with page number - but it needs to know how many pages there is.

  ```
    from selenium import webdriver

    #driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    url = "https://advanced.name/freeproxy?ddexp4attempt=1&page="

    for page in range(15):
        print('--- page', page, '---')

        driver.get(url + str(page))

        all_ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-ip]')
        all_ports = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-port]')
        for ip, port in zip(all_ips, all_ports):
            print(ip.text, port.text)
  ```
- using `while` and clicking link to next page - you don't have to know how many pages there is.

  ```
    from selenium import webdriver

    #driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    url = "https://advanced.name/freeproxy"
    driver.get(url)

    while True:

        print('--- page ---')

        all_ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-ip]')
        all_ports = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-port]')
        for ip, port in zip(all_ips, all_ports):
            print(ip.text, port.text)

        try:
            # go to next page
            link_to_next_page = driver.find_element_by_link_text('»')
            link_to_next_page.click()
        except:
            # exit loop if there is no more pages
            break
  ```

Comment: I'm surprised it detects it as a script when I use headers, cookies etc?  I want to do this without opening a browser though?  Is there a way of rendering it without selenium?

Comment: Also can you explain your code a little?  ```'//td[@data-ip]' and  '//td[@data-port]'``` That's how you grab id's with selenium?  Also this ```for ip, port in zip(all_ips, all_ports):``` what does the zip part do?

Comment: I search separatelly IPs and PORTs and later I use `zip(lall_ips, all_ports, ...)` to create pairs `(ip, port)`.

Comment: `xpath` is popular method to search elements in `xml` and `html`. `'//td[@data-ip]'` searchs all tags `<td data-ip>` and  `'//td[@data-port]'` all tags `<td data-port>`. `xpath` can be used in module `lxml` and in frameworks `selenium`, `scrapy` but not in `beautifulsoup`. `xpath` may have more complex rules - like CSS selectors.

Comment: After the print statement I am doing driver.close() but if I do this it only prints the first IP and then throws an error "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: Tried to run command without establishing a connection"  I need to close the browser after each iteration.

Comment: why do you use `drive.close()`? It closes browser. If you want to print all values then DON'T close it inside `for`-loop but afer `for`-loop. After using `driver.close()` you would have to use again `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` to work with other pages.

Comment: So for the site I want to scrape all 15 pages, so once it finishes the first page it goes to page 2 but it opens a new browser every time.  I used driver.quit() and now it's working the way I want it to.

Comment: if you want to get next page then use only `driver.get()` without running `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` again. You should use `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` only once.

Comment: Wait, so is the way I'm doing it dumb?  Closing the browser and then looping the get method again to get the next page?

Comment: yes. Don't close browser to get next page.  I added examples in answer.