# how to get value from hidden input requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying to get the value of the following element :

```
<input id="CheckoutData_GASessionsID" name="CheckoutData.GASessionsID" type="hidden" value="972728534.978155511.1110">
```

with the following code :

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
s1 = HTTPSession()

r = s1.get("https://www.adidas.co.il/en/checkout#Global-e_International_Checkout", headers=headers)
r.html.render(sleep=5)
sessionid = r.html.find("#CheckoutData_GASessionsID")
print(sessionid)
```

I have made the session log in and add an item to cart.
When I run this code, the output is a empty list.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Take a look at the comments

Try:

```
SesID = soup.find_all("input", attrs={"name":"CheckoutData.GASessionsID","type": "hidden"})
```

`SesID` should be a list with all objects satisfying the condition, you will have to iterate this.

Comment: if I do find_all it returns an empty list

Comment: Okay, sorry your implementation is also correct. It seems to me that the element you are trying to scrape can be generated dynamically by JS. Standard page requests libraries do not render JS, try with JS render: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042696/python-requests-html-trying-to-load-all-info-in-jscript

Comment: Try `print(soup)` if you do not find the item you are looking for, it means that you need to render the JS

Comment: how can I render JS without requests_html? it is only supporting python 3.6 and I am using 3.10.

Comment: I managed to render JS, but this just returns a empty list like before